# What is reasonable deviation in Kerbal Space Program contracts?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I tried to align my orbit as close to required orbit as possible, but still it doesn't count as I've reached the designated orbit. Why is that? and what's reasonable deviation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I checked Apogee, Perigee, Inclination, and perfected it as much as I can to the extent that its almost impossible to differentiate my orbit and designated orbit without zooming in to the highest, what am I missing?

Comment: Data files suggest the allowed deviation is 3-7%, depending on the difficulty. I'm guessing you are orbiting in the wrong direction. What does it say when you mouse over the ascending or descending node (AN/DN)?

Comment: Are you orbiting in the correct direction?  And have you let it settle for a while (it has to be stable)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Gedas mentioned in the comment,

> Reasonable deviation is about 3-7% depending upon difficulty

Here the *inclination* **mentioned** was `180 degrees` which means its a `0 degree` inclination in opposite direction *(normal orbit direction being same as that of kerbin's rotation, **west to east**, anti-clockwise when viewed from above horizon, clockwise from below horizon, horizon being the line parallel to Sun's equator and not that of kerbin's or any other planet)*

And in fact, **it is possible** to align with the intended orbit, without even seeing the contract specification, just by aligning with the colored contract orbit **and most importantly in the direction it illuminates** *(you can see in picture 2 that it illuminates clockwise seen from above and that's why it didn't work)*